# What is the source of the quote "You can see a lot, just by looking"?

Tags: quote-source

What is the source of:

> You can see a lot, just by looking. --- Yogi Berra

I'd like a year, at least, and maybe where it appeared in print.

A different version is at https://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/yogi_berra_125285

> You can observe a lot by just watching.

Answer (score 5):

*The Yale Book of Quotations* (Fred R. Shapiro, ed.) attributes it to Yogi Berra "Quoted in *N.Y. Times*, 25 Oct. 1963" in the form:

> You can observe a lot by watchin'.